# Find id of element without class inside a specific element children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have this html code:

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a id="tabb1" href="#tab1" data-translate="pagtab5" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(1)">Tightening Torques</a>
</li>
<li><a id="tabb2" href="#tab2" data-translate="pagtab6" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(2)" class="inactive">Specifications</a>
</li>
<li><a id="tabb3" href="#tab3" data-translate="pagtab7" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(3)" class="inactive">Technical Data</a>
</li>
```

As you see there are two `<li>` elements with the `inactive` class.

I tried to do this and I have

```
$("#tabs").children();
```

But how can I search the specific `<li>` without class `inactive`?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#tabs li a').not('.inactive').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a id="tabb1" href="#tab1" data-translate="pagtab5" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(1)">Tightening Torques</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb2" href="#tab2" data-translate="pagtab6" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(2)" class="inactive">Specifications</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb3" href="#tab3" data-translate="pagtab7" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(3)" class="inactive">Technical Data</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Use method [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

> Description: Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

Comment: @MikeVinyl glad to help mate :) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class selectors.

```
$("#tabs").children(':has(>:not(.inactive))');
// or with a single selector
$("#tabs > :has(>:not(.inactive))");
```

```js
console.log($("#tabs").children(':has(>:not(.inactive))').length);
// or with a single selector
console.log($("#tabs > :has(>:not(.inactive))").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a id="tabb1" href="#tab1" data-translate="pagtab5" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(1)">Tightening Torques</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb2" href="#tab2" data-translate="pagtab6" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(2)" class="inactive">Specifications</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb3" href="#tab3" data-translate="pagtab7" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(3)" class="inactive">Technical Data</a>
  </li>
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** Or without using jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) instead using [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.

```
$("#tabs > li > :not(.inactive)").parent()
```

```js
console.log($("#tabs>li>:not(.inactive)").parent().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a id="tabb1" href="#tab1" data-translate="pagtab5" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(1)">Tightening Torques</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb2" href="#tab2" data-translate="pagtab6" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(2)" class="inactive">Specifications</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb3" href="#tab3" data-translate="pagtab7" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(3)" class="inactive">Technical Data</a>
  </li>
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** If you just want to select the `a` tag then [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) is enough to get it with a single selector string.

```
$("#tabs > li > :not(.inactive)")
```

```js
$("#tabs>li>:not(.inactive)").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a id="tabb1" href="#tab1" data-translate="pagtab5" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(1)">Tightening Torques</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb2" href="#tab2" data-translate="pagtab6" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(2)" class="inactive">Specifications</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tabb3" href="#tab3" data-translate="pagtab7" onclick="CaricaVisualizzaTab(3)" class="inactive">Technical Data</a>
  </li>
```

Comment: It returns all <li> why? and not one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .not() function

`$("#tabs").find('a').not('.inactive');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
$('ul#list li:not([class])')
```

in your case [class] will be inactive

Answer (score 1):

By using javascript we can complete this way:-

```
var liWithoutHtml = document.getElementById('tabs').querySelector("li>a:not(.completed):not(.selected)");
alert(liWithoutHtml.innerHTML)
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8djF/25/) link